# How to make an url dynamically in rails on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting

I have a form in rails :

```
<form class="clearfix" method="GET" action="<%= url_for hotels_path %>">
     <input type="text" name="country" />
     <input type="text" name="city" />
</form>
```

And i want on submit a redirect to the url :

```
/hotels/:country/:city
```

Where country and city are the values of my fields.

How can i manage this, whithout using javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the redirect on server side e.g. like this (untested):

```
class HotelsController < ActionController::Base

    def index
       redirect_to hotels_path + "/#{params[:country]/#{params[:city]}"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant manage this without using javascript because you set the `action` once while parsing your erb template and when you want to change it based on user action you must use javascript. Thats it!